# How to approve SharePoint workflow task from mobile?

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I have an intranet site for change control management system. Approval workflow is associated with the list. On new request creation or editing any item, approval workflow task is created and mail notifications are sending to the concerned person. Now approving manager login to the portal and approve the task.

Now they are asking to enable mobile access of those pending task and approve the same from mobile. How do I achieve this?

They DO NOT want to expose this site to internet or extranet.

Answer (score 0):

Every list in Sharepoint 2007 has a Mobile View. It is optimized to be viewed on small cell phones and such.

You can edit any view and see the mobile URL in the bottom - see an example of mobile views here: [SharePoint on your Phone!](https://web.archive.org/web/20160309042351/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/martinkearn/archive/2006/04/21/580806.aspx).

Regarding your question: You can share the mobile URL to the task list of your workflow and managers (or whomever) can edit list items and therefore approve or reject your items. **However** you said *"DO NOT expose the site to the intranet or extranet"*.
That is not possible. If you have your managers connect to your intranet via VPN or something similar you don't have to expose the list to the intranet.

Or have I misunderstood your wanted usage of "mobile"? How would you want external managers, using an external cell phone with external internet (UMTS, WAP, WiFi) accessing your internal site?